# Camera Calibration and 3D reconstruction: Scaling factor

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I am following this documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

[image]

In the expression above, I have managed to obtain all the matrices except the scaling factor 's'. I am assuming that my object is planar and hence Z = 0. I tried to solve for 's' by substituting a known 2D to 3D map, and I got a value. However, this value seems to give me a correct mapping only for some points, and not for all. Am I doing anything wrong?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the physical size of the object, and is it the same in all images? Then the scale is exactly one, because you are in a calibrated setup.

If either condition above does not apply, then you cannot recover a physically meaningful scaling factor.

Comment: I know the physical size, but why should the scaling factor be one? I just substituted a known 3D(X,Y,0) - 2D (x,y) map into the matrices and solved for "s". I made some progress, have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021733/obtaining-world-coordinates-of-an-object-from-its-image-coordinates

Comment: "Planar" is not the same as "Z=0", unless the plane is the XY plane of your calibrated world frame.