# Obtaining world coordinates of an object from its image coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, signal-processing, camera-calibration

I have been following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) documentation to use OpenCV. In the formula below, I have successfully calculated both the intrinsic as well as the extrinsic matrices(I have made use of the solvePnP() procedure to obtain these matrices). Since, the object is lying on the ground I have substituted Z = 0. Then, I just removed the third column of the extrinsic matrix and multiplied it with intrinsic matrix to obtain a 3X3 projection matrix. I took it's inverse, and multiplied it by image coordinates i.e. su,sv and s.
[image: Formula]

However, all points in the world coordinates seem to be off by 1 mm or lesser, and hence I am getting not so accurate co-ordinates. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The camera calibration will probably always somewhat inaccurate, because for more than 2 calibration images instead of getting one true solution to equation system acquired from calibration images, You get the solution with the smallest error.

The same goes to [cv::solvePnP()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) . You use one of three methods of optimising the many possible solutions for given equation system.

I do not understand how did You get the intrinsic and extrinsic matrices from [cv::solvePnP()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) , which is used to calculate the rotation and translation of the object in camera coordinate system.

What You can do:

- Try to get better intrinsic parameters
- Try other methods for [solvePnP like EPNP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) or check the [RANSAC version](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac)